# Toolkits / Frameworks to develop cross platform app AND web frontend

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, cross-platform

I did quite a bit of research today without comming to a satisfactory conclusion. I need/want to build a service, that has both:

- a web frontend
- cross platform apps (focused on iOS, android and windows mobile)

I found a lot of frameworks, that allow cross platform mobile apps (stack overflow helped a lot), however I couldn't find any that also promotes extensive code reuse with a web frontend.

At the moment I'm favorizing the following solution:
Split the web backend into a REST framework accessed by both the web frontend and the apps (developed with Phonegap to allow reuse of HTML5 / JS surface code where possible).

Since the project-team is rather small, code duplication should be avoided as much as possible.

Is there another solution/framework (I've probably overlooked), that would cater to my requirements more adequately than my intended solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript frameworks you can use for your web frontend and that can help you for cross platform apps are

1. [Angular JS](http://angularjs.org/) - Nice databinding features, dependency injection and MVC framework
2. [ChocolateChipUI](http://chocolatechip-ui.com/) - Theming based css to look like native iOS / Android / WP8

There are other couple of options you can give a shot. Ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

I work at [Backbeam](http://backbeam.io). It is a backend-as-a-service with great support for both mobile applications and web applications. You can write server-side logic and reuse it on all platforms. Here you can read an [overview about the server-side](http://backbeam.io/article/integrate-your-app-with-server-side-logic-and-enjoy-the-benefits) logic functionality.

At this moment is a hosted service but we have plans to release an Open Source edition this year.

If you have further questions we will be glad to assist you :)

Comment: looks promising. Would it be possible to use the javascriptSDK with phonegap for mobile apps? Writing native apps for every platform is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Yes, the JavaScript SDK works in any webview-based framework such as PhoneGap and Titanium Appcelerator. Additionally it works in Node.js and it has the same API for server-side code.

Comment: Nice! Are you going to Open Source all of it?

Comment: Many parts are going to be re-implemented in the Open Source version because we are using different technologies. For example with the Open Source version you will write server-side code in your favorite editor while the hosted version requires you to write the code in the control panel (thus, in the web browser). But the main thing is that it's going to be fully compatible at source code level.